How should I connect a humidifier to a Ruud Ultra furnace?
I have Ruud model #ugfd-07emcks I am trying to hook up a Desert Springs ds-2800 to. Last year I was using the wall adapter but wanted to clean it up and hook it up to the furnace. When I plugged it into the hot and neutral on the furnace board that said humidifier the motor on the humidifier blew. I ordered a new motor but am I missing something about where to hook it to.

Can you post photos of the wiring diagram for your furnace please?

The furnace board humidifier output is full line voltage. The humidifier has a wall adapter; this is a sign that it's not designed for 120 volts. Its install guide mentions that it runs on 24 volts.
This model of humidifier includes a motor. The install guide does not mention how much power the device requires, nor do we know how much power the furnace may have available from its own 24 volt transformer, so it's best to keep the humidifier powered by the power supply that was included with it.
The furnace should have a disconnect switch mounted on or near it - usually this is just a light switch. That likely can be changed for a combination switch-outlet device like this one: (photo credit: lowes.com)

That'll provide an outlet near the furnace and is probably your best strategy for cleaning up the humidifier wiring.

Did you find documentation? That would be a useful link to provide in your answer (on "install guide" in the first paragraph).
